# Why do I always have to xelatex twice to make references work properly?

Tags: xetex, cross-referencing, compiling

I found that I always have to xelatex at least twice to make references work (referring figures or equations), otherwise I have such wrong reference:

[image]

The following error message appears when the references broke,

> reference `xxxxxxx' on page 7 undefined on input line 289

xelatex again often solve this problem. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, so I can get correct reference without running xelatex compilation a second time?

Comment: This is an inherent feature to all TeX binaries (as far as I know). The location (page number/equation number) must be known first and are written to the `.aux` file, lately at the end of the first run, then read in in the 2nd run

Comment: That is usually how references work. They are written to an external file that has to be reevaluated (i.e. read in again on the second pass). Are you by any chance deleting your `.aux` files?

Comment: Some editors (texstudio) are smart enough to detect new references and trigger the command twice for you.

Comment: @daleif I didn't delete any .aux file. So running twice is inevitable?

Comment: @user15964, imagine the label is on page 10 but the reference is on page 5, how is the reference going to know about the label data on page 10? Note that once the reference *is* in the aux file, you don't have to compile twice? It is only when new references are introduced or if one label changes to a new page.

Comment: @daleif I think the process of generating a .aux file should be much faster than the whole process. So why not just run the .aux generating process first, and then run the remaining process? By the way, Can .aux generating process separate from the whole xelatex compilation process? For example, `aux.exe xxx.tex`generate `.aux`. If so, I think there is a way to do it.

Comment: @daleif After all, according to your account, generating .aux file is just a job of counting and ordering `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: How should know what to write to the aux file other than (xe)LaTeX it self? Remember you cannot compare LaTeX to modern systems. Latex is a much different beast, basically the only program that 100% knows how to interpret LaTeX code is LaTeX it self. For example, consider `listings` here the label is given as a key-value pair. How should a preprocessor know this? It cannot in all cases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was the usual 'I have not run LaTeX at least twice in order to make the cross-referencing working!'